# 権限やバッチを獲得したときの通知を本家Stack Overflowで確認したときの言語

Tags: バグ, 仕様, 日本語

以下は、 stackoverflow.com で通知を見たときのスクリーンショットです (2017/04/26)。

[image: 本家スタック・オーバーフローで見たときの通知]

対して ja.stackoverflow.com で通知を見ると下のように見えました (同日)。

[image: 日本版スタック・オーバーフローで見たときの通知]

権限とバッジで、どこを日本語に訳すかが整合していないように見えるのですが、これは期待された動作でしょうか？

Comment: 英語サイトでinboxを見たときに、バッジは日本語で表示されるのに権限は英語で表示されるということですね。確かに統一できそうな気もします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unaristさんが言ったとおり「英語サイトでinboxを見たときに、バッジは日本語で表示されるのに権限は英語で表示される」のようになります。

もし整合を取ろうとすると複数の問題点が発生します。

1. 日本語版のバッジを英語で表示すると、英語版でのバッジと勘違いしやすくなります（アイコンだけが異なります）
2. サイトにもかかわらずに言語を固定すると、「言語設定」等を作らないといけませんが、デフォルトをどっちに設定しても困るユーザーがいます（英語をデフォルトにすると英語読めないユーザーが困るし、日本語に設定すると英語版のサイトをメインに利用するユーザーが困ります）

現状はパーフェクトとは言えませんが、整合を取れていない以外は問題がないと思っていますので、現在更新する予定はありません。もし「機能要求」で何かを提案してくれたら、検討させていただきます。